# How to use key press events in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want the "Add" function to run when I input a number into "LE1" and press the "Enter" key on the keyboard. I also want the line edit to clear its text when I select it for editing.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QDialog

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.Glayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.LE1 = QLineEdit('Input Number',self)
        self.LE1.keyPressEvent(self.KPE)
        Label1 = QLabel('+ 1 =',self)
        self.LE2 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.Glayout.addWidget(self.LE1)
        self.Glayout.addWidget(Label1)
        self.Glayout.addWidget(self.LE2)



    def Add(self):
        Num = float(self.LE1.text())
        math = Num + 1
        ans = str(math)
        self.LE2.setText(ans)



    def KPE(self):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Enter:
            self.Add()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyPressEvent is a method that if you override it that way you are losing the default behavior, besides it is unnecessary since QLineEdit has the returnPressed signal that notifies if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

On the other hand, converting a string to floating can throw an exception so you should prevent that case, another better option is to use a widget that allows only numerical values with QSpinBox or QDoubleSpinBox, or at least restrict the values that are entered into the QLineEdit with a QValidator appropriate.

And finally do not use the word math as a variable name since that is the name of a library that could cause you problems in the future.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.LE1 = QLineEdit("Input Number")
        self.LE1.returnPressed.connect(self.add)
        Label1 = QLabel("+ 1 =")
        self.LE2 = QLineEdit()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE1)
        layout.addWidget(Label1)
        layout.addWidget(self.LE2)

    def add(self):
        try:
            num = float(self.LE1.text())
            num += 1
            self.LE2.setText(str(num))
        except ValueError:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```